# How to get pixels locaton in a view ios

Tags: ios, position, pixel

I need to access the pixel position in a view (viewcontroller's view). In my case I can access the green pixel. What I'm trying to do is to calculate the frame of that green color area in that view.

Comment: You want a bounding rectangle that includes all the green pixels contained in the view controller's view? Do you want green pixels that are actually in the view, or do you also want to include green pixels that come from subviews?

Comment: Yes, need a bounding rectangle that includes all the green pixels contained in the view controller's view. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

convertRect method will be useful in your case

Try this code

```
CGRect frame = [pixel bounds];
frame = [pixel convertRect:frame toView:self.view];
```